# Prevent reactive form to submit and send post request to server

Tags: angular, reactive

I have a small issue, If I for example try to submit an empty form, It sends a post request to my server and I don't know how to prevent that

Here's my form

```
       <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="form" #myForm="ngForm" 
          (ngSubmit)="save()"> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName" class="control-label 
                  required">First name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" 
             formControlName="firstName">


                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lastName" class="control-label 
            required">Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lastName" class="form-control" 
            formControlName="lastName"> 
                </div>
```

and in my app.component.ts

in my constructor i have

```
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
        firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), 
   Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)]],
        lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), 
   Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)]],

    });
```

and save() function for submiting the form

```
    save() {
    let formModel = this.form.value;
    formModel.id = this.Id;

    if (this.Id == null) { 
        this._usermanagementservice.addEmployee(formModel).subscribe(() => {

           //function that reloads table with employees
            this.LoadAllEmployees();
        });
    }
    else {
        this._usermanagementservice.updateEmployee(this.Id, formModel).subscribe(() => {
            this.LoadAllEmployees();
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried if condition in my save func if(formModel.valid) but doesn't work, help :S

Comment: You should remove `#myForm="ngForm"` from your `form` element. You're mixing reactive forms with template forms

Comment: In your question you say "I've tried if condition in my save func if(formModel.valid) but doesn't work". That of course won't work, because you set `let formModel = this.form.value;` You should try `if(this.form.valid){...run your logic...}`

Comment: Really the standard approach is to prevent the user from submitting the form in the first place by disabling the submit button. In your html `<button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>`

Comment: to form be valid, It needs every param from form builder? how can I choose which are required for form to be valid?

Comment: By adding `Validators.required` to the form controls validator array you are declaring that input is required for the form to be valid. If you remove that validator from that input (formControl) you're declaring that input as optional. Again you mixed reactive and template forms in this case too, you will want to remove the `required` directives from your input tags in your html.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks a lot, I'll try both, with disabled button and If conditional

Answer (score 0):

this is how I handle forms...

## Component

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(
  fb: FormBuilder
){
  this.form = fb.group({
     name: ["", Validators.required]
  });
}

submit({value, valid}:{value: IForm, valid: boolean}){
  if(valid){
    ...
  }
}
```

## Template

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit(form)">
  <input formControlName="name" />
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```